# Como uso threads ou algo parecido nesse código?

Tags: vb.net, thread

Galera eu estava precisando usar os `Threads` (ou algo que não trava o programa enquanto o código nao termina de ser executado) nesse código, mas sempre da um erro diferente, por isso preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Eu estava iniciando a ação com um botão.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim var2 As String = "C:\...\Pasta de Video"
    ListView1.Clear()
    PegarImagemDosVideos(var2)
    Esc(var2)

End Sub
```

Que executa essa Sub que filtra alguns dados.

```
Private Sub Esc(ByVal CaminhoPastaVideos As String)

    Dim gp As New ListViewGroup(CaminhoPastaVideos) With {
            .Name = CaminhoPastaVideos
        }
    ListView1.Groups.Add(gp)

    If FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(CaminhoPastaVideos, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count > 0 Then             'Pega os videos soltos na pasta.
        For Each video In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(CaminhoPastaVideos, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv")
            ColocarPastasDestroDoListView(video, gp)
        Next
    End If
    If FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories(CaminhoPastaVideos, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly).Count > 0 Then                                           'Verifica se tem pastas na pasta passada na Sub.
        For Each pastas In FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories(CaminhoPastaVideos, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)
            If FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(pastas, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count = 1 Then            'Se tiver menos que 2 videos joga no grupo anterior.
                For Each video In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(pastas, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv")
                    ColocarPastasDestroDoListView(video, gp)
                Next
            ElseIf FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(pastas, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count > 1 Then
                If FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(pastas, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count >= 1 Then       'Se tiver mais que 1 videos cria um novo grupo e joga os videos nele.
                    Dim gpi As New ListViewGroup(CaminhoPastaVideos) With {
                        .Name = pastas
                    }
                    ListView1.Groups.Add(gpi)
                    For Each video In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(pastas, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv")
                        ColocarPastasDestroDoListView(video, gpi)
                    Next
                ElseIf FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories(pastas, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly).Count > 0 Then                                  'Se tiver menos que 2 videos repete o processo.
                    Esc(pastas)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

E por último ela executa esse código que adiciona as imagens nos `itens` do `listView`.

```
    Private Sub ColocarPastasDestroDoListView(ByVal Caminho As String, gp As ListViewGroup)

    Dim caminho_saida As String = "C:\Users\...\source\repos\ApenasPronto\ApenasPronto\Thumb\"
    Dim caminho_thumb As String
    Dim name_arquivos As String
    Dim formato_imagem As String = ".png"
    Dim xx As Image

    name_arquivos = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Caminho)
    caminho_thumb = caminho_saida + name_arquivos + formato_imagem

    Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(caminho_thumb)
        xx = Image.FromStream(str)
        thumbnail.Images.Add(xx)
    End Using

    ListView1.LargeImageList = thumbnail

    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    lvi = New ListViewItem With {
        .Text = name_arquivos,
        .ImageIndex = cont,
        .Group = gp
    }
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    cont += 1
End Sub
```

Alguns dos erros que eu tive foram nas linhas: `ListView1.Groups.Add(gpi)` e `ListView1.LargeImageList = thumbnail`. Além de nao poder fazer isso `Dim td As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Esc("C:\...\videos"))`por que o `AddressOf` não permite usar `("C:\...\videos")` então como eu resolvo isso?

Galera to um tempão quebrando cabeça com isso, se poderem ajudar a resolver isso agradeço muito.

Comment: Olá @Lucas. Pretende utilizar a `thread` onde? No método `ColocarPastasDestroDoListView`?

Comment: Sim. Essa parte demora um pouco para ser executada e por isso o programa "congela" até que que termine.

Comment: coloca dentro de uma backgroudworcker que o programa continua executando normalmente durante o trabalho
http://www.macoratti.net/vbn5_ept.htm

Answer (score 0):

Experimente desta forma:

```
Private Sub ColocarPastasDestroDoListView(ByVal Caminho As String, gp As ListViewGroup)
    Dim caminho_saida As String = "C:\Users\...\source\repos\ApenasPronto\ApenasPronto\Thumb\"
    Dim caminho_thumb As String
    Dim name_arquivos As String
    Dim formato_imagem As String = ".png"
    Dim xx As Image

    Dim thread as New Thread
    (
        Sub()
            name_arquivos = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Caminho)
            caminho_thumb = caminho_saida + name_arquivos + formato_imagem

            Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(caminho_thumb)
                xx = Image.FromStream(str)

                thumbnail.Invoke(
                    Sub()
                        thumbnail.Images.Add(xx)
                    End Sub
                )
            End Using

            ListView1.Invoke(
                Sub()
                    ListView1.LargeImageList = thumbnail
                End Sub
            )

            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem

            lvi = New ListViewItem With 
            {
                .Text = name_arquivos,
                .ImageIndex = cont,
                .Group = gp
            }

            ListView1.Invoke(
                Sub()
                    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
                End Sub
            )

            cont += 1
        End Sub
    )

    thread.Start()

End Sub
```

A sintaxe e detalhes da linguagem falham-me um pouco, pelo que poderá ter que ajustar alguns pontos.

Outra das soluções seria utilizar um `BackgroundWorker` e os eventos `DoWork`, `ProgressChanged` e `RunWorkerCompleted`, se quiser ter mais controlo sobre o que está a ser feito durante o processamento da `Thread`.